# Pause execution and wait for user input

Tags: bash

I have a script that I am making and I have an issue with it: I would like to pause execution and wait for user input. I thought that I had it with the `read -p -n 1 $foo` command but the system is having issues with this command. Here is my current script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Ititialization

mainmenu () {
  echo "Press 1 to update your system"
  echo "Press 2 to install samba"
  echo "Press 3 to install vsFTPd"
  echo "Press 4 to install the current version of Webmin"
  echo "Press 5 to configure samba for Active Directory"
  echo "Press x to exit the script"
  read -n 1 -p "Input Selection:" mainmenuinput
  if [ "$mainmenuinput" = "1" ]; then
            updatesystem
        elif [ "$mainmenuinput" = "2" ]; then
            installsamba
        elif [ "$mainmenuinput" = "3" ]; then
            installvsftpd
        elif [ "$mainmenuinput" = "4" ]; then
            installwebmin
        elif [ "$mainmenuinput" = "5" ]; then
            configuresambaforactivedirectory
        elif [ "$mainmenuinput" = "x" ];then
            quitprogram
        elif [ "$mainmenuinput" = "X" ];then
            quitprogram
        else
            echo "You have entered an invallid selection!"
            echo "Please try again!"
            echo ""
            echo "Press any key to continue..."
            read -n 1
            clear
            mainmenu
        fi
}

# This builds the main menu and routs the user to the function selected.

mainmenu

# This executes the main menu function.
# Let the fun begin!!!! WOOT WOOT!!!!
```

You may notice at the `mainmenu` function the `read -n 1 -p "text goes here"` entry. That is where I am having the issue according to ubuntu. Can somebody tell me what is going wrong? thanks!

Comment: The shebang is wrong. You're using bash features, so the shebang must be set to `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Please also consider [this Unix.SE question of mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/630788/318461), where `read` and `sh` (instead of `bash`) were also causing trouble.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Should be:

```
read  -n 1 -p "Input Selection:" mainmenuinput
```

Need to put the `n` flag after, as that is is telling read to execute after *N* characters are entered, do not wait for an entire line. Check `help read` and [this for details](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html).

Comment: I have figured it out! Here is the correct code: `read -n 1 -p "Input Selection:" "mainmenuinput"` It now does not wait for the press of the enter/return key :-)

Comment: "illegal option -n"

Comment: If you just want to pause execution and wait to continue in a for loop: `for $whatever; do $whatever; read -n 1 -p Continue?; done`

Comment: @ses See [my comment here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446156/pause-execution-and-wait-for-user-input#comment2363864_446156)

Comment: If you want to hide the typed character you can add the -s option.