# Wait for input while executing bash script

Tags: bash, scripts, input

I have seen this question:
[Pause execution and wait for user input](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446156/pause-execution-and-wait-for-user-input) , but my problem is different.

I have a Command:

```
google-oauthlib-tool --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype --save --headless --client-secrets src/.config/client_secret_71131800372-dop7miagipbqink2ecnr33so61q3li0t.apps.googleusercontent.com.json
```

This command provides a link and we get a **authorization code** on that link. This command waits until we type that **authorization code** on terminal and after typing the **authorization code**, further processing happens.

The output of this command as follow:

```
Please visit this URL to authorize this application: 

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=71131800372-dop7miagipbqink2ecnr33so61q3li0t.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fassistant-sdk-prototype&state=jFHZmMINesXNFbPNR6ZeJcuDVzpmYq&prompt=consent&access_type=offline
Enter the authorization code:
```

Now If I write this command in a bash script called **script.sh** and execute that script, then it doesn't wait for **user input** of **authorization code** and further processing happens.

I want that it should wait for **authorization code** if executing in a **bash script**.

How can I do it??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `read` command to read from `STDIN`.

```
read -n NUM -p "Enter the authorization code:" VAR
```

**NUM**: number of characters to read from `STDIN`
**VAR**: variable to save the input

if you don't know the number of characters or want to read unlimited characters from `STDIN`, you can remove `-n NUM`. this causes `read` command to ended by **ENTER** and save the result(authorization code) to `$VAR`.

Comment: No, the line "Enter the authorization code:" comes automatically while executing the command. So I don't need to read it in a variable. I just need to type it in the terminal.

Comment: you can read input by `read VAR` without any text. if you don't need the authorization code, why do you want to get the code from the input?